# I cannot understand how setValue is working in init() which used in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

I know that useEffect( without any dependencies) only work on Mount So how state updates by setValues in init() here??

I am beginner in mern stack so please if you wnat any info please comment

//Code snippet

```
const init = () => {
        getCategories().then(data => {
            if (data.error) {
                setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
            } else {
                setValues({
                    ...values,
                    categories: data,
                    formData: new FormData()
                });
            }
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        init();
    }, []);
```

//full code for help

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Layout from '../core/Layout';
import { isAuthenticated } from '../auth';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createProduct, getCategories } from './apiAdmin';

const AddProduct = () => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        name: '',
        description: '',
        price: '',
        categories: [],
        category: '',
        shipping: '',
        quantity: '',
        photo: '',
        loading: false,
        error: '',
        createdProduct: '',
        redirectToProfile: false,
        formData: ''
    });

    const { user, token } = isAuthenticated();
    const {
        name,
        description,
        price,
        categories,
        category,
        shipping,
        quantity,
        loading,
        error,
        createdProduct,
        redirectToProfile,
        formData
    } = values;

    // load categories and set form data
    const init = () => {
        getCategories().then(data => {
            if (data.error) {
                setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
            } else {
                setValues({
                    ...values,
                    categories: data,
                    formData: new FormData()
                });
            }
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        init();
    }, []);

    const handleChange = name => event => {
        const value = name === 'photo' ? event.target.files[0] : event.target.value;
        formData.set(name, value);
        setValues({ ...values, [name]: value });
    };

    const clickSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setValues({ ...values, error: '', loading: true });

        createProduct(user._id, token, formData).then(data => {
            if (data.error) {
                setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
            } else {
                setValues({
                    ...values,
                    name: '',
                    description: '',
                    photo: '',
                    price: '',
                    quantity: '',
                    loading: false,
                    createdProduct: data.name
                });
            }
        });
    };

    const newPostForm = () => (
        <form className="mb-3" onSubmit={clickSubmit}>
            <h4>Post Photo</h4>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="btn btn-secondary">
                    <input onChange={handleChange('photo')} type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*" />
                </label>
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="text-muted">Name</label>
                <input onChange={handleChange('name')} type="text" className="form-control" value={name} />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="text-muted">Description</label>
                <textarea onChange={handleChange('description')} className="form-control" value={description} />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="text-muted">Price</label>
                <input onChange={handleChange('price')} type="number" className="form-control" value={price} />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="text-muted">Category</label>
                <select onChange={handleChange('category')} className="form-control">
                    <option>Please select</option>
                    {categories &&
                        categories.map((c, i) => (
                            <option key={i} value={c._id}>
                                {c.name}
                            </option>
                        ))}
                </select>
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="text-muted">Shipping</label>
                <select onChange={handleChange('shipping')} className="form-control">
                    <option>Please select</option>
                    <option value="0">No</option>
                    <option value="1">Yes</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="text-muted">Quantity</label>
                <input onChange={handleChange('quantity')} type="number" className="form-control" value={quantity} />
            </div>

            <button className="btn btn-outline-primary">Create Product</button>
        </form>
    );

    const showError = () => (
        <div className="alert alert-danger" style={{ display: error ? '' : 'none' }}>
            {error}
        </div>
    );

    const showSuccess = () => (
        <div className="alert alert-info" style={{ display: createdProduct ? '' : 'none' }}>
            <h2>{`${createdProduct}`} is created!</h2>
        </div>
    );

    const showLoading = () =>
        loading && (
            <div className="alert alert-success">
                <h2>Loading...</h2>
            </div>
        );

    return (
        <Layout title="Add a new product" description={`G'day ${user.name}, ready to add a new product?`}>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
                    {showLoading()}
                    {showSuccess()}
                    {showError()}
                    {newPostForm()}
                </div>
            </div>
        </Layout>
    );
};

export default AddProduct
```

Comment: it is used in then callback, which means it will wait for response to come, then it will set these values to state and then it will rerender component, becase state was changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that the useEffect without any dependencies will run once on mount. So that means that the function `init()` is gonna be called at least once on mount, right? So whatever action you have in your init function will be called once. You don't need dependencies in order to set a state.

Comment: If the state changes, is then useEffect run?

Comment: no, that is not the case @hacksrinja